# Как связать данные формы <input type="radio"> и <input type="hidden">?

Tags: html

Имеется несколько элементов на странице (наименование и цвет):

```
<input type="radio" name="catname" value=""> Томас
<input type="hidden" name="color" value="blue">
<input type="radio" name="catname" value=""> Джеральд
<input type="hidden" name="color" value="black">
```

Если выбрать Томаса, то форма передает его имя и последний цвет в списке (в этом случае `"black"`).
Можно ли связать `catname` и `color` вместе при выборе радио-кнопки?

Comment: Если выбрать `<input type="radio">` перед словом "Томас", то запрос будет выглядеть так: `catname=&color=blue&color=black`. Слова "Томас" в нём не будет, а цвета, на самом деле, передаются оба.

Comment: ошибся, данные для передачи как: catname="Томас"&color="blue"

Answer (score 1):

Может, как-то так:

```js
$(".cats").on("change", function() {
    var currentColor = $(this).data("color");
    $(".color").val(currentColor);
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="cats" name="catname" data-color="black" value="Томас">
<input type="radio" class="cats" name="catname" data-color="white" value="Джеральд">
<input type="hidden" class="color" name="color" value="">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Можно и "как-то так". Но если уж использовать JS с jQuery, то можно и без костылей в виде скрытого поля обойтись.

Comment: @Regent, чем плох хиден фиелд? Ида, в другом случае нужно будет сабмитить тоже используя джквери, а так - как хочешь, не?